# Is this a good method for storing lists of items in an SQL Database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, binary-data

This is just a very general database management question. Say I have a list of people, and I want to store a second list for each row in that table. Here is my solution.

Table of Items that a person could possibly have;

[image: Table of Possible Items]

Table of people who have a combination of those items;

[image: Table of People with Items]

Explanation;

```
John has an order of 6, which is 4 + 2, or a Cheeseburger and a Milkshake.
Mary has an order of 25, which is 16 + 8 + 1, or a Soda, Hotdog, and Fries
```

What I'd like to know is whether or not there is already terminology for this type of list storage, and what the upsides / downsides are to doing it this way as opposed to storing multiple keys. I'd also like to know whether or not any database management systems handle lists-within-lists in a similar manner already, and if I wouldn't have to worry about implementing my database like this.

Comment: How do you know a 6 is 4+2, and not 2+2+2?

Comment: This style only works when a list can only contain either 1 or 0 of each item (like chmod permissions). As soon as the person order's more than 1 you're 100% screwed. Your best bet is make an `order` and `order_item` table to tie the `person` together with the `items` that they order.

Comment: But it works fine if the items are unique, correct? Like a list of interests on a dating website?

Comment: The approach is called bit-masking. Yours isn't true bit masking because you are summing numbers, therefore you can get false results in cases that @TabAlleman outlined. It's an efficient technique, used in *nix systems for storing attributes about permissions - you can represent multiple attributes and their values with a single number - which is what you tried. Now, while it's efficient and reduces storage requirements, it's absolutely ultra bad for storing relations. You have a relational database and you have relations. Create another table where you store relations of users and food.

Comment: Yea.. you just have to decode the number into a list of binary places, then split that list into rows, then join that split-row list to your `items` table to determine the `name` of the item (sql server is not going to do this in any easy way.. you have a shot with Teradata and `strtok_split_to_table` function, but that's another post...) Why not just store each item ordered individually in that `people` table, or better yet further normalize it and create a new table that ties the `person` to the `items` they chose.

Comment: This is what I'm asking. I assume it would be more storage-efficient, because you only store one number as opposed to a list of entries, with a performance trade-off.

Comment: Yeah I think true bit-masking would be like if you used a 6-digit number for Order, where the first digit was the number of Fries, the second digit was the number of Milkshakes, etc.   Except I'm not sure how you'd handle an order for more than 9 of one particular item.  If you're storing interests on a dating site, you don't have to worry about someone having the same interest more than once.   But this technique would not be performant if you ever wanted to match two members by their common interests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is horrible practice. You will get multiples that add up to the same thing. You will be continually translating which is bad for performance. Read about normalization before doing any database design. DO not consider using a realtional database in any nonrelational fashion until you try the realtional solution. If you truly have a non-relational need that can;t be solved that way, then a relational database is not the right tool for data storage for your need. This is not one of those cases. This is a relational problem and should almost always be solved realtionally.

Generally this sort of thing is solved by having an Items table with the list of items available. The Customer table with details about the customers. An order table with details about the order such as date time, customer etc. and an Order detail table with specific list of items that were in that order. Of course when you do this you need to set up prepfer FOreign Keys and indexes.

Comment: But what if I'm storing a unique list, and the order doesn't necessarily matter? Say, a list of interests on a dating website? Is the performance-space tradeoff really not worth it at large scales?

Comment: It's absolutely not worth it, almost at any point. You cannot store multiple relations in a single number. Worst part is that you can't query that number using SQL because you need to decypher its meaning first.

Comment: @Maurdekye that data is still relational. Those interests belong to a person. The order of the data is not important but being able to separate them certainly is. If you wanted to find all people with a certain interest you would first have to parse the entire table and then find those with that value. UGH!!

Comment: Is it not efficient to check if a binary number contains a certain power of 2? It seems like a simple bitwise operation.

Comment: By the way, the decoding and management of the database would be abstracted away within the model, so there would be no extra difficulty for the remainder of the team working with this database.

Comment: It's not efficient. For every user, you must repeat the operation of masking the integer. This integer you need to mask depends on how many foods you have. Every time you add a food, you need to add 1 bit to the integer, rounding to the next largest. For 8 foods, you have 1-byte int to mask. Soon, if you have 128 foods, you have 128 properties - therefore you have 128 bits. This can get out of hand quickly. and you need to parse this number every time you query for a relation. I can assure you this is MUCH SLOWER than you think it is. Just use proper relational design.

Comment: @Maurdekye, abstracting it away makes it worse not better.  You shoud never think in those terms. Teams need to understand the meaning of the data.   You are thinking in terms of ease of developers, when, in database work, the first thing to consider is data integrity, the second thing to consider is database performance. You never sarrfice one of these because you find a techinique easier to understand  (or worse more elegant!) than a proper relational database design. Databases are optimized to use relational techniques.

Comment: You also need to think about how the data will used later on. I guarantee you are going to want to do reporting at some point and this design makes that ridiculoauly slow. Stop thinking in terms of handling one order at a time and think how much slower this will be when you need to decode millions for a report.

Comment: Consider how ridiculous the query becomes when you get a request from management that is some like "I want to see the sales quantity per item broken down by hour". In the design you suggested it would take a monumental amount of work. In a properly normalized system the query would be super fast to execute and write.